# How to use the xtunitroot test in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to use the xtunitroot command in Stata to test for the stationary of variables in Panel Data, but I wonder whether to use this one:

```
xtunitroot llc x
```

or this one:

```
xtunitroot llc x, lags(1)
```

What is the purpose to use "lags(1)" in the command?

I'm quite new in Stata, so any helps will be deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: While the explanation in `help xtunitroot` doesn't add much to my understanding of the option, the discussion in the xtunitroot section of the **Stata Longitudinal-Data/Panel-Data Reference Manual** (xt.pdf) does have a deeper discussion. It is included in the Stata installation (since version 11) and accessible from within Stata - for example, through Stata's Help menu. My takeaway is, omit that option unless you have substantive reasons to override the default.

Comment: @William Lisowski: Thank you so much, Mr. William Lisowski. I would be deeply grateful if you could help me with another problem: how to do Arellano-Bond test for AR(1) and AR(2) in Stata after estimation by xtdpd command?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about that technique. I can tell you that in the manual I referred to, the section following `xtdpd` is `xtdpd postestimation`. That section documents `estat abond` as perhaps the test you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. William Lisowski. I am really appreciated it!